# Newbie at PHP: How can I fill out a form from values in an array?

Tags: php

I am not sure whether I am asking this with the right words, I just started learning PHP. I have a list of 200 URLs and I want to get their geoIP location. Geobytes provided me with a PHP code that gets me the city and that is fine, but the code itself is:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=213.171.218.127');
 print $tags['city'];
```

And I would like to ask whether it is possible to fill out the part after 'IpAddress=' with a list of URLs automatically? Can I say something like: Here is an array, where I have put the URLs for which I need you to get the meta tags, now put these after the 'IpAddress=' and get the tag from each of them?

I am sure this is very simple, so even if you could tell me how to formulate my problem so that I can easily search for answers on Google, I'd be happy with that as well!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ips = array('ip1', 'ip2', 'ip3');

foreach ($ips as $ip)
{
    $tags[] = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=' . $ip);
}

print_r($tags);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know how I can get it to display only one of the tags? Using  print_r($tags['city']); doesn't work.

Comment: Change it to  `$tags = get_meta_tags('url-snipped'); echo $tags['city']` if all you care about is printing that one tag.  (Remove the `print_r()` line, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
$ipAddresses = /* ... */;
foreach ($ipAddresses as $ip) {
    $tags[] = get_meta_tags("http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=$ip");
}
```